# Php send command to c++ Windows application

Tags: php, c++, communication

I'm curious how to achieve this. I'm not even sure what to google.

If I have a web server and I want to make a php page with a button. When that button is clicked my c++ application running on a remote machine will execute a function.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this? Does a library for this already exist? If not what should I google to get started on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the remote machine running on the server, or separate?

Comment: Google for: `windows communication foundation`, `dcom`, and `win32 launch process on remote computer`

Comment: What if the application is written in C?

Comment: Use PHP exec to call your c++ program. exec is used to execute command line utility. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Is the os on the remote machine linux or windows? Also is your app compiled for windows or linux?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP-Backticks

http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.execution.php

You can call any executable and take their output in a variable.

Eg.

> $result = `mycppapp.exe`

Regards

Comment: I think question was not about starting, but rather about controlling already running app? Plus in the original question it clearly says that Windows host is remote. So backticks are not a solution here.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work for me. I want it to execute code/function in an already runnin application. Not to start up a brand new process.

Comment: Best way would be to make a listener on a certain port. Then send a request with php over that port. This will trigger the function then. There seem to be nice addons like this http://www.sfml-dev.org/ which seem to simplify such an endeavor

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on your C++ app.
But basic idea is like this.
In your html you define a button, when button is clicked - you initiate AJAX GET or POST to your php program (there are variations possible, you can simply do it via forms).
In turn your php can initiate connection to remote Windows host and this is where it gets tricky.

- Is your Windows C++ app able to receive commands via network? In other words does it have any REST API? Or any other means to control it via TCP?
- And what exactly do you want to do? Simply start this app or control it in some way?

If it has REST API - then it's simple. You can start off with something as simple as php curl to send REST messages.
If it doesn't have any remote control API and only CLI - then you would have to start using remote powershell I would assume.
Something like this [powershell - execute cmdlet remotely with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855329/powershell-execute-cmdlet-remotely-with-php)

Comment: Rest was dependent on cpprest DLL so my client wasn't looking forward to adding more dll's to the project. But yes my c++ application has access to a network. The thing i don't know how to have it connect to a php page. Maybe when the button is clicked on php page it could write out a variable to another php page. Then every so often have my c++ application connect to that page and check for the variable. If true it executed my function. Would that be good or is there a better method?

Comment: If you can start listening on a socket in your C++ app - then you can receive  messages over network. I don't think going other way around would be a good solution, as you would be constantly polling server side for event that might not be even there. You can do a mockup simple app in C++ and in PHP. C++ will start listening on a certain port for messages and PHP would send such messages.